# Message Passing Broken in Chrome 19?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging

As of Chrome 19.0.1084.46, there is an extension of mine that has stopped working for me and others. It involves grabbing tab URLs, then sending them to a script. It all worked fine before upgrading and there's no mention of what has changed on Google Code docs. Does anyone know what has changed to cause this issue?

bg.htm:

```
c="Whatever";
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse) {
 sendResponse({ val:c });
});
```

do.js:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest(null,function(resp) { c=resp.val; });

alert(c); // DOES NOTHING IN CHROME 19
```

Comment: Did some extension stuff last night in Dev Channel Chrome 19, and the message passing worked fine. I am not sure what the problem here is, but I wanted to at least let you know that I have seen it work in Chrome 19, so there is hope.

Comment: Have you tried placing the `alert` in the callback: `chrome.extension.sendRequest(null,function(resp) { alert(resp.val); });`?

Comment: I can't even get `alert('hello')` to work in there, but that was a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass something else than `null`, and `alert(c)` should be inside the callback although I'm not sure if alert really works for content scripts.

`Console.log` works for content scripts but the message will be logged into the debugger of the tab where that script is injected into (and not in the extension's debugger).

Comment: That's the new difference! The parameter can no longer be `null`. I simply put `{x:""}` as a dummy and it worked fine. Thank you!